# How to group postgres left join so it's just an array of the join data?

Tags: sql, typescript, postgresql, drizzle

I am new to postgres and sql in general. (I've been using ORM's for a while) and recently moved onto using Drizzle.

I have two tables, a `projects` and `users` table and my left join is like this:

```js
const data = await db
  .select()
  .from(projects)
  .where(eq(projects.slug, slug))
  .leftJoin(projectPdfs, eq(projects.id, projectPdfs.projectId));
```

This gives me this data:

```json
[
  {
    projects: { id: 1, name: 'redacted', slug: 'redacted' },
    pdfs: {
      id: 1,
      assetUrl: 'redacted',
      projectId: 1,
      requestTimeMs: '4859.872999999672'
    }
  },
  {
    projects: { id: 1, name: 'redacted', slug: 'redacted' },
    pdfs: {
      id: 2,
      assetUrl: ''redacted',
      projectId: 1,
      requestTimeMs: '4859.872999999672'
    }
  }
]
```

Is there a way to do group using SQL to get the data output to be this? Or is it normal to change your datastructure once you've got it from the db?

```json
 [
    {
      id: 1,
      assetUrl: 'redacted',
      projectId: 1,
      requestTimeMs: '4859.872999999672'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      assetUrl: 'redacted',
      projectId: 1,
      requestTimeMs: '4859.872999999672'
    }
  ]
```

I actually tried using `groupBy` but I didn't get the results I was after.

Answer (score 0):

I started using Drizzle ORM yesterday so I'm walking on a very thin ice still. The only way I achieved this was the following:

```
db.select({
  id: projectPdfs.id,
  assetUrl: projectPdfs.assetUrl,
  projectId: projects.id,
  requestTimeMs: projectPdfs.requestTimeMs        
}).from(...)
```